# c# making my paint brush Alias and smooth

Tags: c#, gdi+, paint

How can I adjust my code so that the brush paints smoother with aliasing? I'm not sure how to adjust or what to change. I know there is a SmoothGraphics property but I'm unsure of where to place it or how to use it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Polisher
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool paint = false;
        SolidBrush color;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.BackColor = Color.White;
            //this.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
            //this.TransparencyKey = Color.Empty;
        }

        private void uiOpacitySlider_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var opacityVal = (uiOpacitySlider.Value) / 100.0;

            this.Opacity = opacityVal;
            uiOpacity.Text = (uiOpacitySlider.Value).ToString() + "%";
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g1 = uiCanvas.CreateGraphics();
            g1.Clear(uiCanvas.BackColor);
        }

        private void uiCanvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            paint = false;
        }

        private void uiCanvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            paint = true;
        }

        private void uiCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (paint)
            {

                color = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                var size = (int)numBrushSize.Value;

                Graphics g = uiCanvas.CreateGraphics();

                // center paint brush onto cursor
                var xPos = (float)(e.X - ( (float)size / 2.0) );
                var yPos = (float)(e.Y - ( (float)size / 2.0) );

                g.FillEllipse(color, xPos, yPos, size, size);
                // e is the mouse, in this case e.x is the current X position of the mouse.
                g.Dispose();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't do your drawing in `MouseMove`.  Do it in `Paint`.  Call `Invalidate()` in your mouse event(s) to force redraw.  Track data in variables so you know what/how to draw.

Second, don't use `CreateGraphics` if you can help it.  It's volatile, and not the proper way to render in a Form.

Regarding quality, you can do things like:

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

There are other properties available, of course, depending upon precisely what you want to adjust.

Comment: @DonBoitnoot Would you be able to show me how to implement the fixes and suggestions you've mentioned as I'm not entire clear on how to do that please. I'd appreciate it.